# Windows Phone 8.1 black space below application bar on 720p devices

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Many apps have this black space (3mm or so) below the application bar on 720p devices under WP 8.1. Looks like the app is too short for the screen. You can see it in emulator too.

Is this a bug of the dev preview? Is there a way to avoid this?

Add a new screenshot of BING NEWS. This is NOT a dubpicate question! Please notice, only on 720p devs. and WP 8.1 dev. prev.

[image]

Comment: No, I can't see what you mean.  Can you post an example screen shot of your emulator?  Does it show up on a screen capture on a 720p device? (volume up + on/off button)

Comment: I see no such thing on my Lumia 1520 with dev preview.

Comment: Apps like Start Screen Customizer or DubStep Pad or all the Bing apps have this issue too

Comment: also just a PS - nice creepy ninja profile pic dude ;)

Comment: @Chris ... this is an other issue ... I do not mean the open app bar. look at the screen

Comment: very funny claus - if you can't see it you should change your display. þ the app bar is grey the space below is black.

Comment: The bing apps have this issue not more but other still. seams to be a problem with the pivot template. May be only wp8 apps on wp 8.1